# How to get email delivery status with webdav

Tags: c#, .net, webdav, exchange-server

how can I check if an email is sent using webdav?Is there any delivery status poperty or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

WebDav is an interface you can use and Exchange Server has implemented it so you can access Exchange over port 80 (same as HTTP). You seem to ask about whether you can see, inside Exchange, if WebDav is used for a particular task. While that question is better suited on http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com, it is unlikely that such a flag exists.

Instead, program your WebDav utility in such a way that you set some flag yourself. That way it'll be easy enough to track down how a message was sent. Is this an option for you? You may want to check [this page for some WebDav to Exchange examples](http://www.msexchange.org/articles/Access-Exchange-2000-2003-Mailbox-WebDAV.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I' ll check the link that you have posted!